# UIView not showing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a view controller this view controller has a UIView which was added in the builder. In viewdidload the UIView is hidden but when you click a button the UIView should appear but doesn't. I have linked the Outlets correctly and linked the UIView to the files owner but no luck. It was working until i modified something in the xib.

```
- (void)buttonRVClick:(id)sender{

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    viewRV.alpha = 1;
}];
self.viewRV.hidden = NO;

[self.tableView2 reloadData];
}
```

Comment: does the `-buttonRVClick:` method get called?

Comment: I think the secret lies in "It was working until i modified something in the xib" ...

Comment: @staticVoidMan, yes the event for the button does fire, i added a trace ant looks fine

Comment: Check the frame of your view and report back the results.

Comment: dude this code enough it works you could have dome OUTLET related error check outlets and other stuffs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then I think you need to check that self.viewRV is still connected correctly in IB.

```
if (!self.viewRV.superview)
{
    NSLog(@"whoops")'
}
```

Also set the view to not hidden before animating - Not sure why you're setting it to hidden in the first place. If you're using the alpha use the alpha.

then set the alpha to Replace `viewRV.alpha = 1.0`

Comment: just added the code in viewdidload and never says whoops

Comment: now it says whoops, what could be missing I've looked in the xib and i can't find the mistake

Comment: i may have to delete the xib and start that view again

Comment: found it the, sent events were not hooked up

Answer (score 0):

Replace `viewRV.alpha = 1` with `viewRV.hidden = NO` and `viewRV.hidden = YES`.

Comment: hi, No luck with that

Comment: What is the alpha value of the view in your xib?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)buttonRVClick:(id)sender{

self.viewRV.alpha = 0.0;

self.viewRV.hidden = NO;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    viewRV.alpha = 1;
}];

[self.tableView2 reloadData];

}
```